# Are libuv handles active after close but before close_cb?

Tags: c, libuv

libuv has a `void uv_close(uv_handle_t* handle, uv_close_cb close_cb)` method to close handles which takes a callback.

As the title says, is the handle active (in terms of I/O) before `close_cb` is called? For example, can a UDP handle fire a receive callback and a timer handle fire a timer callback before `close_cb`?

The closest thing in the documentation I could find is "Handles that wrap file descriptors are closed immediately but close_cb will still be deferred to the next iteration of the event loop." However, I'm not sure which handles fall into this criteria and more importantly, what "closed immediately" means exactly (stops all callbacks? stops only *new* callbacks? removed from the event loop entirely?).

Comment: I actually went spelunking through the source to figure this out and got stumped. I'd be very interested in the answer too, because I assumed callbacks would be guarded by a check of the "active" flag and... I don't think they are. I *can*, however, tell you that in every kind of handle I checked, the handle is "stopped" and the underlying I/O watcher mechanism is closed. See eg. [UDP](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/unix/udp.c#L92).

Answer (score 1):

The type of a libuv handle determines whether the handle would fire its dedicated callback even after `un_close(handle)` completed and before the `uv_close_cb` is invoked, so there's no general answer for that.

For example, `uv_tcp_t` may fire the callback `connect_req->cb()` or `uv_udp_t` may fire `send_cb()` (from `uv_udp_send_t`) again while many other types of handle don't (see `uv__finish_close()` in [/src/unix/core.c](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/unix/core.c)).

All handles are no longer able to use as soon as [`uv_close()`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/unix/core.c#L114) cleared the flag `UV_HANDLE_ACTIVE` of the given handle and set the flag `UV_HANDLE_CLOSING`. You are NOT allowed to use the closing handle by invoking corresponding functions immediately after `uv_close()` , if you still do so, the corresponding functions may either return error or give you assertion failure (e.g. [`uv_timer_start()`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/timer.c#L67) and [`uv_poll_start()`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/unix/poll.c#L119))

`uv_close()` doesn't remove the handle from the event loop, instead it moves the closing handle to the internal list of the loop (only for later closing process), then you call `uv_run()` again, which  will actually process all closing handles, depending on the type of closing handle, the closing handle fires its callback whenever necessary (e.g. `uv__stream_destroy()` in `uv__finish_close()`) , finally `uv_run()` invoke the callback `uv_close_cb`
(see [the source at here](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/unix/core.c))